# Does transistors and other semiconductors always require printed circuit boards (green ones) and soldering to connect

Tags: transistors, pcb, diodes, circuit-design, semiconductors

Do the devices like transistors and other semiconductors always require to be connected in the printed circuit boards the green strips and do they always require to be soldered into the board , cant we just always use wires ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, the PCB is a 'component' in its own right. But when it isn't, it becomes more of a practical and economic question.

Sometimes the PCB provides controlled impedance connections, or equal length connections between ICs. That would be difficult or impossible to reproduce with wires.

Often, for DC and low frequency circuits, the PCB 'only' provides electrical connection, and mechanical support. There's no fundamental reason why the components can't be glued to a substrate, and wired point to point.

In fact, when I'm developing circuits, I will often 'dead-bug' components (glue them upside down, with the legs sticking up in the air) and connect pins together with wire, or leaded components. However, while that works electrically for one prototype, it's completely economically infeasible for larger quantities, or production.

The fragility of a wired dead-bug board, compared to the robustness of a PCB, means that if I have time, then I will make a PCB even for one prototype, if it's more than a few components.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly not! In te extreme case, neither PCB nor solder are required.

This ["Ladybird book"](http://www.mds975.co.uk/Content/george_dobbs_trf_radio.html) for young children shows how to "breadboard" a radio - it's pretty self explanatory, and you can start with an actual breadboard (if Mother no longer needs it for slicing bread!)

[image]

Obviously after the prototype stage, a PCB has obvious advantages of repeatability and ease af construction, and reliability, with no danger of those wires slipping out from under the cup washers.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can just wire them together:

[image]
(from http://www.righto.com/2018/01/examining-1954-ibm-mainframes-pluggable.html)

There is also so-called ["dead bug"](https://makezine.com/2012/10/08/a-fine-example-of-dead-bug-style-circuit-wiring/) soldering where you lay a chip on its back and build a circuit around it.

However, all mass-produced electronics will use a printed circuit board, as they can be assembled by machine and then soldered all at once in an oven. They are usually green but not always.

The other disadvantage of "dead bug" or other non-PCB manual assemblies is that they're more fragile.

Comment: Any transistor?

Comment: Transistors are no different. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o4Y8v7qhL6U/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: You are missing out those where the pcb plays a major role in things like impedance, or distributed element filters.

Comment: So i can make any complex circuit of today which has wires etc like phone with wires

Comment: No. Have you thought about how many transistors that are in a phone? Millions and millions. To wire those separately is not feasible

Comment: @MrGerber 'phones with wires' predate transistors, so the answer can be zero rather than millions.

Comment: Given the context, I interpret the question as "can I make any complex circuit of today like phones, with wires", then the answer is definately no.

Comment: I don't know what modern phones you have that has zero transistors, but if that is the case, well - that makes it more likely it's possible to make it entirely with a wired construction at least.

Comment: So almost any diode , transistor sensor can be used in circuit with wires ?

Comment: Yes, but not all electronic products or building blocks will function as expected when constructed entirely with wires.

Answer (score 2):

> cant we just always use wires ?

Properly designed PCBs (green, red, blue or any colour within reason) will minimize connection loops that can (and inevitably will) be either a source of EMI or be susceptible to EMI. So, if you require a high performance EMC product you will use a PCB with at least a ground plane and appropriately close decoupling capacitors in noisy or susceptible areas. You won't get that with wires.

PCB ground planes: -

[image]

Wires cannot give anything like the robust electromagnetic interference (EMI) performance of a ground plane.

Comment: Workable circuit would they be able for that ?

Comment: @user174176 sorry I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application, some circuits will have such strict requirements that a wired construction simply would not work. 

A wired construction would typically be limited on a number of parameters, the following spring to mind (not all these would necessarily be applicable at the same time).

- Assembly cost (both time and complexity)
- Assembly repeatability
- Physical envelope
- Electromagnetic Noise compatibility (both emitted and received)
- Speed requirements - Stray effects (inductance, capacitance)
- Transmission lines, impedance control, length matching etc

Cost and physical size is most likely the reason to why it is typically avoided in simple circuits where the signal requirements are not as demanding.